# Android Dev: Local SVN for Android Projects?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, version-control

I'm trying to set up a VCS for my Android projects in Eclipse. Right now I have the SVN and Subclipse plug-ins installed to Eclipse. I know how to connect to a remote SVN like a google code project url but I don't want that, I want to set up a local SVN on my own computer. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you know about [git version control](http://git-scm.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create the local repository, and then tell subclipse where it is.

A svn repository is basically a folder, with a structure of files and folders. If you use a svn client like Tortoise SVN, you just need to

1. create a folder, give it a name and open it,
2. right click the folder and on the context menu go to TortoiseSVN->"Create repository here".

You will now have your SVN repository created.

In eclipse, it's the normal process to import the new svn, but when it asks for the svn URL, use the filepath to the local svn folder. In my case it's

```
file:///C:\Users\Lee Scott Reis\Desktop\LocalSVN
```

If you want to host a public SVN, then you'll need a svn server.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: After I create the repository with TortoiseSVN can I uninstall it?

Comment: Yes, you can uninstall TortoiseSVN, or use many other SVN utility software to create SVN repositories, but I'd recommend keeping one as it can be really useful.

Comment: Ok I got it to work but I have another question: I commited the project to the trunk directory. Is that correct? Now I noticed a branch/ folder, do I want to commit to that folder when creating a branch?

Comment: Thats a simple one: you just need to understand what Apache wanted when they invented it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion#Branching_and_tagging

Comment: You work on the Trunk, which is the main development line. Whenever you have a stable release version, you "tag" it, and continue to work on the Trunk. Whenever you want to develop and test new ideas, or do anything that's not going directly into the main version goes to a branch (you copy the whole project there). The idea is to merge the Branch latter into the Trunk, and when it's on a stable version, you Tag it.

Answer (score 3):

trust me ... just use git. it's a very simple install, no need to maintain a server or anything. and it makes it very easy to push your changes to a remote repository if/when you want to start collaborating with someone else.

Comment: Ok, how do I use git with Eclipse and Android then?